# Is there a reason to catch an exception only to throw it again if the try block doesn't contain code that explicitly throws the exception?

Tags: java

Is there ever a reason to write code like this?

```
try {
    foo();
} catch (final Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

If `foo()`'s declaration is `void foo() throws Exception` I get why this might make sense, it'd be better to explicitly handle the exception rather than just re-throw it though, but I can at least see how it makes sense (`foo()` throws a checked exception so it must be caught or thrown).

However, if `foo()`'s declaration doesn't say it `throws` an exception, is there a point to this, or is it just bad coding?

Comment: If you don't catch it, it just goes up the call stack like the newly-thrown exception would.  Normally you would only catch and rethrow if you wanted to write to a log, or change the exception to something more meaningful in this context.

Comment: You may want to do something with the exception, logging for example, then pass it on.

Comment: or you could wrap it in some kind of high-level exception

Comment: Or add some relevant info that is available here to the Exception's message

Comment: So I'm not crazy, okay. I saw this today and thought it was very odd to catch the exception but _only_ throw as opposed to throwing it and logging it or handling it in a way that made sense.

Comment: Catching `Exception` is dangerous! It also means you catch all unchecked exceptions (`RuntimeException` and derivates). Don't do that! Or catch/rethrow them before `Exception`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, there is certainly no point to do that. However, most software I've seen has multiple level logging for exceptions which are propagated usually up several (5+ layers in the call stack). Something like this is common:

```
catch (final Exception e) {
    logger.log(Level.ERROR, srcInfo, "Exception in ...");
    throw e;
}
```

But this can be misused also since the calling method may do its own logging and you will be left with a lot of repetition in the logs, but this is a design issue. More commonly, the method will catch a specific exception, for example

```
catch (CustomPlatformException e) {//log and throw e
    }
```

then re-throw it to a higher-up method which will catch all subclasses of `Exception` and log separately a general fault in the specific flow.

```
catch (Exception e) {//Log general failure in flow, usually at a higher logging level
    }
```

Comment: "But this can be misused also since the calling method may do its own logging". yes, yes, yes! Please to not "log-and-rethrow". Usually you either handle, or rethrow, not both.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly like this, but you might see a pattern similar to this called *exception translation* (Effective Java item 61).

In the first place, `foo()` should not be declared to throw `Exception`.  If it does and you can't change it, then you might write something like this:

```
try {
    foo();
} catch (final Exception e) {
    // maybe test the actual class of e here
    throw new MoreAppropriateException(e);
}
```

You can also use this pattern to translate exceptions into something more appropriate for your abstraction.  To use the example from EJ, say you have a method that uses an `Iterator` to retrieve an element.  You don't really want to expose the fact that you're using an `Iterator` in case you change it later, so you catch any `NoSuchElementException` and translate it into an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Likewise, if you're writing an API that internally uses a third-party API, you'll want to translate any third-party exceptions to avoid exposing your use of the third-party API.

Comment: Good points. I should have specified I was talking about exceptions in general as opposed to `Exception`, but this is still very good insight.